# Spring support for a mock framework?

Tags: spring

I'm new to springs and looking for support for a mock framework in springs.I have come across support for Junit , but couldn't find good documentation for  the support of a mock framework.Please provide some links.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). I have used Mockito with JUnit and you can use mocked Spring beans quite easily with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations. Have it a go.

P.S
Here are few links for you to get started.

http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-autowired-fields/ This one uses TestNG but same is true for JUnit as well.

https://ahlearns.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/spring-3-autowired-unit-tests-with-mockito/

Comment: Yes.I did consider Mockito. But not exactly getting clarity on spring support for it.Could you share some links with examples for the same?

Comment: Added few links that may be useful to you.